# environment variables not working in node js server

Tags: node.js, express, server, environment-variables, dotenv

When i set my username and password directly in a nodemailer server, it works as expected

```
auth: {
    user: 'myusername',
    pass: 'mypassword'
},
```

But on using dotenv, nothing happens

```
require ('dotenv').config();

auth: {
  user: process.env.USERNAME,
  pass: process.env.PASSWORD
},
```

I ran `npm install dotenv` on server side and set up a `.env` file with the variables below:

`USERNAME:myusername`

`PASSWORD:mypassword`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax in your `.env` file is incorrect.  Use equals `=` signs rather than colon `:`.

```
USERNAME=myusername
PASSWORD=mypassword
```

See also:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 5):

As noted in the [dotenv docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), it expects the variables in the format `NAME=VALUE`. Your file should instead contain:

```
USERNAME=myusername
PASSWORD=mypassword
```

Comment: thank you. but it still isn't working after the changes

Answer (score 1):

i was having the same problem when i had the name of env file as **.env.local**
but when i changed the name of the file to simple .env , it worked!